# Parse.com - object not found for update

Tags: parse-platform

I know this question has been asked several times, but I haven't find a fix yet. 
What I did was create a class called Earthquake and a background job which download contents, create an array on Earthquake and then save it through Parse.Object.saveAll(...). 
Here some code (note: actualEarthquake is an object of the "Earthquake" class)

```
actualEarthquake.set("updated",updated);
            actualEarthquake.set("place",place);
            actualEarthquake.set("type",type);

            //Save it to array
            earthquakes.push(actualEarthquake);
            writeToLog(pid, "Item -> " + i);
        }

        Parse.Object.saveAll(earthquakes, {
            success: function(earthquakes) {
                status.success("Yayy it's working... maybe");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                writeToLog(pid,"Error -> " + error.message);
                status.error("Such error much crash");
            }
        });
```

When I run the background job everything works ok except the saveAll which catch and error: "object not found for update". I have already tried applying and ACL to each single object but nothing changed.
The strange thing is that I have already another app which have almost the same code and... it works!!

Answer (score 2):

Add this before you make saveAll call:

```
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```